# NO_PUBKEY and BADSIG signature errors when updating

Tags: 11.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

I am unable to update my ubuntu 11.10
and this what appears on my terminal

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease                      
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                             
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports InRelease                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg [72 B]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release.gpg                           
Get:3 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg [198 B]                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                                   
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                                   

Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg                   
Get:7 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release                               
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release.gpg                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner amd64 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Get:10 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                         
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner TranslationIndex              
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release                       
Get:11 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release                     
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources/DiffIndex                
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Sources/DiffIndex          
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources/DiffIndex            
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg                    
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex         
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex          
Get:12 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release                        
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex      
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Sources                  
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Sources              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Sources                   
Get:13 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [1,201 B]               
Get:14 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,214 B]                
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main amd64 Packages           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources/DiffIndex                    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources                      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Sources                
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Sources            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en_US             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:15 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [748 B]                 
Get:16 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [765 B]                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources/DiffIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en         
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Fetched 9,184 B in 9s (939 B/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B725097B3ACC3965
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D6B6DB186A68F637
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 187206A44933B6AB
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6D3B959722E58263
W: GPG error: http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 464AD83D4631BBEA
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```